# How to use Memcache Protocal

Tags: java, memcached, spymemcached

I have observed that the spymemcached client communicate with memcached server very fast. I googled the sample implementations, but not found.  Only the theoretical documentations.

Has any one got sample source (code, any other supporting jars) which explain how data transfer happens in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memcached protocol is a TCP based protocol that usually passes over port 11211.  If you run a packet sniffer on your machine, you should be able to see the memcached commands pretty clearly since the protocol is fairly simple.  Here's the protocol definition:

https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt